# My phone has a touch/pointing bug

Tags: touchscreen, bugs, touch

I bought a new phone the other day and I noticed I can't deactivate an alarm from the Clock app, when I pressed the pink checkbox, it would not check. But this happens only for the top alarm, the other ones that are below the first one, work fine.

I started searching Google for a "touch" bug and the only thing that was a little helpful in my situation was finding the option to show the pointing circle on each touch. This allowed me to provide the next screenshot:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>click screenshot for larger variant</sup>

So, when I try to press on something, say the checkbox on the first alarm, the device actually thinks I'm pointing in 2 directions at one, one above and one below.

Can somebody, please, provide me with some clearance on this issue? It's really annoying, given that the phone is brand new.

Comment: What is your phone? This isn't a problem with the clock app, you might have a faulty touchscreen. Take it to a service centre or ask for a replacement from wherever you bought it.